# how to store downloaded content in ios app's local directory persistently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

We are developing an app like [saavan](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/saavn-bollywood-english-hindi/id441813332?mt=8) for ios device, which stores the downloaded musics offline and let users access it unlimitedly. i read the apple [storage guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) that says,

1) Downloaded content should not be stored in /documents directory
2) And data in /library directory would be deleted in rare situations, when device runs in low memory or user restores the device etc.

What we trying to achieve is to store the downloaded musics persistently in app local storage that could not be deleted in any situation unless the user deletes the app.

Consider that a single music would consume 4 mb space, so if the user downloads 200 musics it would consume 800 mb in an average case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think it's the *caches* directory.

Comment: Store it in the Documents directory.  The guideline refers to content which is usually downloaded over and over.  Anything meant to be persistent should be in Documents.  That said, the user still can delete the data through the Settings app, and there's no way to prevent that.

Comment: @Avi apple guideline says any re-creatable contents should not be stored in documents directory.

Comment: @trojanfoe the same applies for cache directory too,cache directory is inside library directory,

Comment: @VivekParamasivam So what?  If it needs to be deleted then it needs to be deleted.

Comment: @trojanfoe i'm exploring the way to prevent downloaded contents from being deleted.

Comment: @VivekParamasivam You can't so stop worrying about it. Just chuck the files in the *Caches* directory.

Comment: @trojanfoe So you mean no way ?